# jquery mobile - how to pass a parameter when moving from one data-role page to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm writing a small and simple jquery-mobile app.

The first page is a list view of categories, which is populated by json retrieved from an ajax request.

The second page should be called when the user clicks on one of the categories.

It should open with a list of items that will also be retrieved by an ajax request. The request should get a category_id as a parameter.

I'm planning on using the multi page pattern (multiple pages in the same html).

This is my js code:

```
$(function() {

initListByUrl($("#categories_ul"), 'http://localhost:3000/categories');

});


function initListByUrl(id, requestUrl) {
$.ajax({
    url: requestUrl,
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var items = []
        $.each(data, function(i, elem) {
                items.push('<li id="cat_li_'+i+'"><a href="#items">' + elem.name + '</a></li>');
            });
        id.html(items).listview('refresh');
    }

});
}
```

and the id of the category is another field in elem, lets assume  - elem.id.
How can i pass this id as a parameter to the code that will build the second page?
Should I use session storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript stack to push and pop the data required for every page, like for instance you can `push` the `elem.id` in the calee and then `pop` and use the `elem.id` in the page called or viewed.

```
var stack = [];
stack.push(3);
var data = stack.pop();
alert(data);
```

Comment: and how about passing the elem data to the event itself?

Comment: to which event you want to pass data?

Comment: var e = jQuery.Event( "keydown", { keyCode: 64 } );
    // trigger an artificial keydown event with keyCode 64
    jQuery( "body" ).trigger( e );

Answer (score 0):

I've created a plug-in under the MIT license which is compatible with jQuery Mobile 1.4+. The plug-in allows you to use URL parameters to communicate between pages. In addition, since the data is in the URL, it handles page refreshes as well as the user going directly to a specific jQuery Mobile page in your app. You can find it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler).